# Change URL Routing in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am Working On AngularJs, If I Type On Browser like 
  http://localhost/vistorsday it went to, 
  http://localhost/vistorsday/vapp/home.
  I Want To Change My URL to http//localhost/vistorsday/home or http//localhost/visitorsday.

Here is my code below

```
.state('vapp', {
   abstract: true,
   url: '/vapp',
   templateUrl: 'tpl/vtapp.html',
   controller: "headerCtrl"}
)
.state('vapp.home', {
   url: '/home',
   templateUrl: 'tpl/home.html',
   controller: "homeCtrl"}
) // JavaScript Document
```

Please help me out with this Situation.

Comment: show me your routing code.

Comment: Here is my Routing Code.

state('vapp', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/vapp',
        templateUrl: 'tpl/vtapp.html',
        controller: "headerCtrl"
    })
      
    .state('vapp.home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'tpl/home.html',
        controller: "homeCtrl"
 
    })

Answer (score 0):

Just change the URL of the vapp, so that it points to '/' instead of '/vapp' (unless you have any specific reason to keep it as '/vapp').

```
.state('vapp', {
   abstract: true,
   url: '/',
   templateUrl: 'tpl/vtapp.html',
   controller: "headerCtrl"}
)
```

Hope this helps.